# In a privately held family-owned company is there any way to salvage this or no?

Tags: work-environment

I've been at this company with approximately $50 million in revenue for the past 5 years; sometimes I think that the longer I stay here the more conditioned/desensitized I become to dysfunctional workplace behavior. I stayed silent about it until now because it never affected me until recently when the company ran out of people to pick up the slack created by this dysfunction. That, and up until now I've been able to keep my head down, live comfortably, and focus on my job role without having to be involved in the ridiculous shows I've seen over the years.

In this situation, relatives of the owners are in executive/director/president positions and run the departments such as shipping, accounting, information technology, etc.

Time and time again, when leadership failures or business design, structure, or process mistakes cause are responsible for a decline of revenue; instead of the owners or relatives of the owners being held accountable for their mistakes; it is up to individual staff members and departments not ran by the owners or their relatives to pick up the slack.

Let me give you the most recent example. Revenue is down and continues to decrease for 3 months. It is only after month three that the company discovers that since month 1, only 3 out of 4 orders have been making it into the hands of customers due to orders undelivered by a subset of private delivery carriers. The president of shipping (one of the owners) and his team receive a report from logistics software everyday showing the delivery status of all orders. No one from shipping department noticed there was a delivery issue. It was only after someone from marketing (a department not managed by an owner or family member) looking into shipping software for customer addresses for a mail campaign that this was this noticed.

Am I wrong to thing that it any highly functioning company, heads would be rolling up and down the shipping department? Like entire leadership teams let go?

Instead, the immediate response was denial; that it must be an issue with the software, etc. When it was confirmed that this was an actual problem; no one is held accountable or let go. Instead, people outside the shipping department like in sales operations, marketing, and creative are having to call up individual sub-carriers to find out information about why orders are not/were not being delivered and track the status of delivery independently of the shipping department in Excel spreadsheets on top of their existing workloads combining the slack from 3 to 4 departments!

Is every company this bad? People who make a fuss about it are typically let go or quit to find job roles more aligned with that they were initially hired for before they got the tasks from 3 to 4 departments due to the kinds of failures described above. Very few people are left; and when I asked some of the remaining people not related to the owners what their take on this is; their response is that they are just trying to solve problems and plug holes in revenue.

Other than existing ownership selling the company or stepping away from business and staying in advisor/product innovation roles; what can be done from a company perspective? And from an employees perspective, can anything be done other than take it for how it is or quit?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @Dsyfunctional. I suspect your question may benefit for an [edit] to put more focus on the core question since it's not that clear what practical issue you're truly trying to solve. Right now most of this reads more like complaints about your company, but I think there's a good question at the heart of this around how much change you can effect bottom-up in family-run businesses. Even if the answer is likely, as you suspect, "very little". Check out the [tour] and [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Companies are not required to be ran efficient.  If the those running the business want to make the mistakes you describe, then they free to make those mistakes, just don't get stuck in the crossfire.  Even if you CYA (aka cover your ass), the owners might not care, and they can fire you.  Entirely up to you if you determine the positives out weight the negatives.

Answer (score 11):

> Other than existing ownership selling the company or stepping away
> from business and staying in advisor/product innovation roles; what
> can be done from a company perspective?

Plenty *could* be done. But it doesn't sound like anything *will* be done.

> And from an employees perspective, can anything be done other than
> take it for how it is or quit?

Seems unlikely that an employee could do anything here. After 5 years, you must know this.

You've put up with it for 5 years. If you can't put up with it any longer, then find a new job and quit this one.

Comment: To pre-empt discussion: we don't recommend "[quit your job](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/is-quit-your-job-an-acceptable-answer)" answers but Joe's answer isn't only saying that. The conclusion is correct: if you're unable to change this situation you can either accept that or move on. To paraphrase AAM: [OP's company sucks and isn't going to change](https://www.askamanager.org/2017/05/your-boss-sucks-and-isnt-going-to-change.html)

Answer (score 7):

I'm a realist. There's likely nothing you can do as a non-family employee. Many family owned and run businesses have been, are, and always will be highly dysfunctional.

You are in essence a serf plowing your field for the King and Queen. Unless you marry into the nobility there's no change that you'll likely be able to effect.

Comment: I’d think you have to marry, and then go on a course of ruthless elimination. Could make an interesting movie.

Comment: _"Save the princess, marry her and become the court jester"_ ;)